# Parse.com Data Browser not Displaying Anything?

Tags: parse-platform, mbaas

This happened shortly after the issue that occurred today, not too long ago.

[image]

status.parse.com says everything is operational. Is my data lost?

Edit: Oh and querying does not work. I get the following:

```
Error: no results matched the query (Code: 101, Version: 1.2.19)
```

Comment: Please don't let me be alone with this problem....

Comment: Don't worry, you're not alone. I'm also experiencing this issue. I unfortunately lost all the classes I made as well. I tried to export my data in case it was simply the data browser not working, but it didn't include anything I had been working on.

Comment: Same problem earlier today too. My data has started to reappear though, to match the object count in the Classes index on the left of your screenshot. I am missing some columns on my objects though :-(

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced this issue and all the data appears to have come back at this time.

Perhaps when you checked status.parse.com they had not yet discovered the issue.  Looking at it now I see that there was an incident today that could explain the blank data browser.

As a startup Parse.com is likely to have significant growing pains.  It is up to each developer to decide if the issues are worth the benefits of the service.

Comment: Well it's back to normal now! This week is first time Parse has been giving me any trouble.